# Python: for loops if self.bricks[i - 1].rect.colliderect(self.ball.rect): IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, for-loop, pygame

So, I'm making a breakout clone, and I'm having a rendering issue, I think. What I have coded it to do is when the ball hits a brick, it A.) bounces the ball B.) makes the brick disappear, and C.) removes the brick from a list of all bricks so that it doesn't render it again. It does this with a for loop:

```
for i in range(len(self.bricks)):
    if self.bricks[i - 1].rect.colliderect(self.ball.rect):
      if self.ball.rect.right > self.bricks[i - 1].rect.right or self.ball.rect.left < self.bricks[i - 1].rect.left:
        self.ball.speed[0] *= -1
      elif self.ball.rect.top > self.bricks[i - 1].rect.top or self.ball.rect.bottom < self.bricks[i - 1].rect.bottom:
        self.ball.speed[1] *= -1
    self.bricks[i - 1].image.fill([0,0,0])
    self.bricks.pop(i - 1)
```

the way that I did it before wouldn't make the brick disappear, it would stay on the screen but be removed from the list. I've tried several solutions and can't come up with anything better than this. The problem is that now it tells me that self.brick[i - 1] is out of range. I think that it's popping the the brick before running the rest of the loop. I don't know why it would, but its the only thing that makes sense to me.

Any help is appreciated. If you need to see more code then just ask.

Anthony Fancella

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`range(len(self.bricks))` is precomputed before the loop is executed. However, you are popping objects out of the list during the iteration, and thus `i` will be out of bounds. Try marking the bricks to be removed during this iteration by adding a new property on the brick class/object and then removing them all at once afterwards.

Comment: well, it works but now the bricks all stay rendered, but are removed from the list.